# c++: std::vector of std::function with arbitrary signatures

Tags: c++, function, vector

Is it possible to create an `std::vector` that can hold an `std::function` with any signature?
(The function arguments would all be pre-bound.)

I tried `std::vector<std::function<void()> >`, since if I only have one `std::function` of that type I can bind any function to it.

This does not seem to work inside a vector: if I try to add a function with `std::bind` to the vector that has a signature other than `void()`, I get:

```
No matching member function for call to 'push_back'
```

Is there a way to do this?

**Edit:**

I just remembered that `std::function<void()>` does allow you to bind any function that returns `void` as long as the arguments are pre-bound with `std::bind`, it does not allow you to bind any signature though, but for my purposes it's generic enough, so the following works:

```
class A
{
public:
    void test(int _a){ return 0; };
};

A a;
std::vector<std::function<void()> > funcArray;
funcArray.push_back(std::bind(&A::test, std::ref(a), 0));
```

Comment: the arguments would be prebound

Comment: I might see this working with variadic templates, but I wouldn't be able to come up with the code.

Comment: Do you mean multiple signatures in the same vector?  Or are you just writing a generic algorithm.  If the later, you could use a template to achieve this.

Comment: @Als I edited the question with the error message i get

Comment: @Benj I mean multiple signatures in the same vector. basically i want to have a simple array of functions ready to be called, that should not be limited to a specific signature.

Comment: So how would you know which arguments to use when calling them if you don't know their signature?

Comment: @fontanini the arguments would be prebound via std::bind as stated above

Comment: Do not describe code. Quote it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

void hello() { std::cout << "Hello\n"; }
void hello2(const char * name) { std::cout << "Hello " << name << '\n'; }

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::function<void()>> v;
    v.push_back(hello);
    v.push_back(std::bind(hello2, "tim"));
    v[0]();
    v[1]();
}
```

How are you doing it?

Comment: What if the return types are different?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create an std::vector that can hold an std::function with any signature? (The function arguments would all be pre-bound.)

So you're wondering if you can use a vector to hold objects of different types except that you've wrapped them all up in a single type?

Yes, you can store a bunch of items that all have the same type in a vector.

---

Or maybe you're trying to ask "How do I wrap callable objects such that they'll have the type I need?"

bind can handle the special case where you only need to remove or reorder parameters in order to get something convertible to the common type. In order to handle the general case where you may need choose the return type, add parameters, etc., you simply have to write new functions. Lambda's can make it easy to do that inline:

```
std::vector<std::function<common_signature> F;

double foo(std::string);
// for a common signature of void()
F.push_back([]{ foo("hello"); });

int bar(void);
// for a common signature of int (int)
F.push_back( [](int i) { return bar() + i; });

int baz(void);
// for a common signature of std::complex<double> (void)
F.push_back( []() -> std::complex<double> { return {0,baz()}; });
```