# Vector of std::function with different signatures

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-function

I have a number of callback functions with different signatures. Ideally, I would like to put these in a vector and call the appropriate one depending on certain conditions.

e.g.

```
void func1(const std::string& value);

void func2(const std::string& value, int min, int max);

const std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> functions
{
    func1,
    func2,
};
```

I realise the above isn't possible, but I wonder if there are any alternatives I should consider. I haven't been able to find any yet, and I've experimented with `std::bind` but not managed to achieve what I want.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Why not just give them the same signatures. You do not have to use all the parameters in the function

Comment: Why do you need to use a vector for that? A vector can only contain types that share the same type (polymorphism counts). If you have functions with different signatures, you won't be able to do e.g. `for( auto&& function : functions){ function(); }`, so you need to keep them separated anyway, or uniformize their signatures (but if they do have different signatures, this last option feels like brute-forcing them into the vector...)

Comment: @EdHeal - I guess I could. Was just wondering about alternatives.

Comment: @JBL - Ultimately that's what I wanted to do. I guess what you're saying is it's not possible.

Comment: What do you *exactly* want to do? Look at these varying answers.. I'll vote to close for "unclear what asking."

Comment: You have couched your question in terms of possible solution(s).  What you need to do is to state what you actually want to achieve. I think there is still time to do this before the votes to close stack up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++: std::vector of std::function with arbitrary signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565019/c-stdvector-of-stdfunction-with-arbitrary-signatures)

Comment: Alternatively, how do you expect to *use* this vector of functions? This is what we need to know. There's no point asking how to stuff these objects into a vector. Putting stuff into a vector is never interesting on its own. Making use of the vector later, perhaps by reading from them, is interesting

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You haven't said what you expect to be able to do with `func2` after putting it in a vector with the wrong type.

You can easily use `std::bind` to put it in the vector if you know the arguments ahead of time:

```
const std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> functions
{
    func1,
    std::bind(func2, std::placeholders::_1, 5, 6)
};
```

Now `functions[1]("foo")` will call `func2("foo", 5, 6)`, and will pass `5` and `6` to `func2` every time.

Here's the same thing using a lambda instead of `std::bind`

```
const std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> functions
{
    func1,
    [=](const std::string& s){ func2(s, func2_arg1, func2_arg2); }
};
```

If you don't know the arguments yet, you can bind references to some variables:

```
int func2_arg1 = 5;
int func2_arg2 = 6;
const std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> functions
{
    func1,
    std::bind(func2, std::placeholders::_1, std::ref(func2_arg1), std::ref(func2_arg2))
};
```

Now `functions[1]("foo")` will call `func2("foo", func2_arg1, func2_arg2)`, and you can assign new values to the integers to pass different arguments to `func2`.

And using a lambda function instead of `std::bind`

```
const std::vector<std::function<void(std::string)>> functions
{
    func1,
    [&](const std::string& s){ func2(s, func2_arg1, func2_arg2); }
};
```

This is pretty ugly though, as you need to keep the `int` variables around for as long as the callable object (the closure or the bind expression) referring to them exists.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using std::bind the way you have shown (as I know the args at compile time) is what I had tried when I said I had experimented with std::bind but couldn't get it to work. I now can thanks to your response.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is possible through `polymorphism`. The idea is to create a class with a specific signature, which at runtime will call different methods. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

void foo(int) {
    std::cout << "I'm foo!\n";
}

int bar(char, double) {
    std::cout << "I'm bar!\n";
}

class MyFunction {
    public:
        virtual ~MyFunction(){}

        virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

class MyFunctionA : public MyFunction {
    public:
        virtual void operator()() {
            foo(4);
        }
};

class MyFunctionB : public MyFunction {
    public:
        MyFunctionB(std::function<int(char,double)> f, char arg1, double arg2) : fun_(f), arg1_(arg1), arg2_(arg2) {} 

        virtual void operator()() {
            fun_(arg1_, arg2_);
        }
    private:
        std::function<int(char,double)> fun_;
        char arg1_;
        double arg2_;
};

int main() {
    using MyFunPtr = std::unique_ptr<MyFunction>;
    std::vector<MyFunPtr> v;

    v.emplace_back(new MyFunctionA());
    v.emplace_back(new MyFunctionB(bar, 'c', 3.4));

    for ( auto&& myfun : v ) {
        (*myfun)();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can make the derived classes as complicated as you need be, but since in the end they all have the same interface you will be able to call all of them.

Answer (score 4):

For `C++ 17` [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) can be used for holding `std::function`s with different signatures. In this case, the function [std::holds_alternative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/holds_alternative) allows you to distinguish between them at runtime:

Sample:

```
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>


using FooInt = std::function<void(int)>;
using FooStr = std::function<void(std::string)>;

using FooVariant = std::variant<FooInt, FooStr>;

void foo(int a){
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

void bar(std::string a){
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<FooVariant> v;
  v.push_back(foo);
  v.push_back(bar);

  for(auto& f: v){
    if (std::holds_alternative<FooInt>(f))
      std::get<FooInt>(f)(1);
    else if (std::holds_alternative<FooStr>(f))
      std::get<FooStr>(f)("hello");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct answer to your question is "NO". Any runtime container would only let you store objects of the same type and std::function<> instantiated with different signatures will be different data types.

Generally the reason you may want to have "a vector of functions with different signatures" is when you have something like the below (three step processing where input interface is unified (`buffer& buf` and output interface is unified `on_event(Event evt)`), but the layer in the middle is heterogeneous `process_...(...)`

```
receive_message(buffer& buf)
  switch(msg_type(buf))
    case A: 
    case B:
    ...

process_A(A& a, One x, Two y)
  ...
  dispatch(Event evt);
  ...

process_B(B& b, Three x);
  ...
  dispatch(Event evt);
  ...
```

In a solution not involving metaprogramming you'd typically pre-cook a functor doing the end-to-end at initialization time and store those in the vector:

```
vector <std::function<void(buffer& buf)>> handlers;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've got an int and a string, you cannot put them in one vector but you can put them in one struct or `std::tuple<>`. The same applies for two function types.

Comment: that's not the question

Comment: @BeyelerStudios: He explicitly asks for an alternative to `vector<>` to hold the two functions. Isn't `tuple<>` capable of doing that?

Comment: by "a number of callback functions" I understand the number is arbitrary at runtime, tuples won't do here

Comment: Even then it's quite likely the set is quite bounded, and you'd just set the functions you don't need to `nullptr`.

Answer (score 0):

As JBL mentioned: how would you call them, if you don't know their signatures?

Think about turning your `min, max` arguments into a parameter type with some base class `Parameter`, the callback signature will be `void(const std::string&, const Parameter&)` or `void(const std::string&, const Parameter*)` in case you wish `nullptr` to indicate no additional parameters. Now your callbacks will need to check if they were given the right parameters if any. That may be done by using a visitor, typeid or an enum. There's pros and cons to all of those.

How will you decide on which callback to call? I think you should turn your C-style callbacks into handler objects, they might implement a function `bool canHandle(const Parameter&)` to test if the handler is applicable to the parameters presented.

Jonathan Wakely and Svalorzen present their approach where the parameters and the function are one and the same object (1-to-1 relationship). In this example they are separate (in case you have multiple-to-multiple relationships):

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <vector>

class ParameterBase {
public:
    ParameterBase(const std::string& value) : m_value(value) { }
    virtual ~ParameterBase() { }
    const std::string& GetValue() const { return m_value; }
private:
    std::string m_value;
};

class HandlerBase {
public:
    virtual bool CanHandle(const ParameterBase& params) const = 0;
    virtual void Handle(const ParameterBase& params) = 0;
};

class Handler1 : public HandlerBase {
public:
     class Parameter : public ParameterBase {
     public:
          Parameter(const std::string& value) : ParameterBase(value) { }
          ~Parameter() { }
     };

     bool CanHandle(const ParameterBase& params) const { return typeid(Parameter) == typeid(params); }
     void Handle(const ParameterBase& params) {
          assert(CanHandle(params));
          const Parameter& p = static_cast<const Parameter&>(params);
          // implement callback1
     }
};

void foo(const std::vector<HandlerBase*>& handlers) {
     Handler1::Parameter params("value");
     for(auto handler : handlers)
         if(handler->CanHandle(params)) {
             handler->Handle(params);
             // no break: all handlers may handle params
             // with break: only first handler (if any) handles params
         }
}
```

Comment: How would you call them? Visitor pattern, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

`std::function` erases the exact type of the function object but preserves the function call signature. If you cannot `bind` the extra arguments in advance as Jonathan Wakely recommends, you can use a `boost::variant< std::function<...>, std::function<...> >` as your vector member. At the call site you can then check if the vector contains the right kind of function object and call it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.I was able to get what I wanted working using std::bind following Jonathan Wakely's response.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how useful this would be for you, it is based on `boost::any`, redundant parameters are ignored. You can add `try...catch` for `boost::bad_any_cast` to prevent crash in case of mismatch between arguments' and parameters' types. Though I think regular `std::bind` is a better choice.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2ba3991a06a1e68)

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct IGenericFunction
{
    virtual ~IGenericFunction() = default;

    virtual void call(boost::any a1 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a2 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a3 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a4 = boost::any{}) = 0;
};

template <typename... Args>
class GenericFunction : public IGenericFunction
{
public:
    GenericFunction(std::function<void(Args...)> f) : _f{ f } {}

    virtual void call(boost::any a1 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a2 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a3 = boost::any{}
                    , boost::any a4 = boost::any{}) override
    {
        call_func(std::make_tuple(a1, a2, a3, a4)
                , std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
    }

private:            
    template <typename Tuple, std::size_t... Indices>
    void call_func(Tuple t, std::index_sequence<Indices...> s)
    {
        _f(boost::any_cast<
                typename std::tuple_element<Indices, Params>::type
           >(std::get<Indices>(t))...);
    }

    std::function<void(Args...)> _f;

    using Params = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

template <typename... Args>
std::shared_ptr<IGenericFunction> make_generic_function_ptr(void(*f)(Args...))
{
    return std::make_shared<GenericFunction<Args...>>(f);
}

void func1(const std::string& value)
{
    std::cout << "func1 " << value << std::endl;
}

void func2(const std::string& value, int min, int max)
{
    std::cout << "func2 " << value << " " << min << " " << max << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IGenericFunction>> functions;

    functions.push_back(make_generic_function_ptr(&func1));    
    functions.push_back(make_generic_function_ptr(&func2));

    for (auto f : functions)
    {
        f->call(std::string("abc"), 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the function pointer, and cast std::function<int(int)>* to void*, it can be compiled successful, but sometimes it will cause segmentation fault:

```
int Fun(int a)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return ++(++a);
}

int main()
{
    std::function<int(int)> originPFun = Fun;
    void *ppFun;
    // ppFun = (void*)&Fun; // This way will cause segmentation fault
    ppFun = (void*)&originPFun; // This way can run seuccessful and get right result
    std::function<int(int)> *pFun = (std::function<int(int)>*)(ppFun);
    std::cout << (*pFun)(5) << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```