# std::function variable arguments in one vector/map

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std-function

how could one do this in c++ today without using two separate holders?

```
typedef std::function<void(int a, int b)> f1; 
typedef std::function<void(int a)> f2; 

std::vector<f1> m;

void add(f1 f)
{
    m.push_back(f);
}

void add(f2 f)
{
    // add one more (unused) parameter to f2 so we can add f2 to f1 vector holder?
}
```

can we somehow overload f1 function to include different set of parameters?
could this be solved by variadic templates nowdays or something similar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vector of std::function with different signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158504/vector-of-stdfunction-with-different-signatures)

Comment: Already three close votes, with a duplicate that is the *exact opposite* of the problem at hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new lambda matching the new signature and add that instead:

```
void add(f2 f)
{
    m.push_back( [g = std::move(f)](int a, int /* unused */){ g(a); } );
}
```

Comment: I'd make the second parameter `auto&& /* unused */` myself.

Answer (score 0):

This wraps a `std::function` in a lambda that ignores any extra args:

```
template<class R, class...Args>
auto ignore_extra_args( std::function<R(Args...)> f ) {
  return [f = std::move(f)](Args...args, auto&&...)->R{
    return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  };
}
```

it gets trickier if we don't want that needless layer of type erasure.

You need to find the longest prefix of `Args...` which you can invoke a given object `f` with, then invoke `f` with it.  This involves some tricky metaprogramming.

It is far easier if you ask the caller to pass in a signature:

```
template<class Sig>
struct ignore_extra_args_helper;
template<class R, class...Args>
struct ignore_extra_args_helper<R(Args...)> {
  template<class F>
  auto operator()( F&& f ) {
    return [f = std::forward<F>(f)](Args...args, auto&&...)->R{
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
  }
};
template<class Sig, class F>
auto ignore_extra_args( F&& f ) {
  return ignore_extra_args_helper<Sig>{}(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

which saves on possible overhead.

```
template<class F, decltype(std::declval<F const&>()(1,1))* =nullptr>
void add(F&& f) {
  m.push_back(std::forward<F>(f));
}

template<class F, class...Unused>
void add(F&& f, Unused&&...) {
  add( ignore_extra_args<void(int)>(std::forward<F>(f)) );
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0e96f18115844e6)