# Store multiple functions into array C++ for looping

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

I have two functions called

1. `void funcBlock(A a, B b, int C, long& R, long& M, double& D)`
2. `void funcNormal(A a, B b, long& R, long& M, double& D)`

In main method, I would like to use the values from these two function by looping them such as,

main method:

```
combineFunc cfs[] = { funcBlock, funcNormal }
for (int idx = 0; idx < 2; idx++) //Cause it has two functions to loop over
{ 
  combineFunc cf = cfs[idx];

  //Do the rest of the stuffs
}
```

I encounter error :

> error: cannot convert ‘void (*)(A, B, int, long int&, long int&, double&)’ to ‘combineFunc’ in initialization

How do i fix this?

Comment: What is `combineFunc`?

Comment: They accept different parameter types, and different number of parameters. How do you expect the code know which and how many parameters to pass?

Comment: Better tell us what do you want to achieve.

Comment: `cfs[]` is an array.  All elements of the array need to be of the same type.  "Function  Pointer" is not a type.  Each of the function pointers need to be of the same type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vector of std::function with different signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26158504/vector-of-stdfunction-with-different-signatures)

Comment: You could write a wrapper function `void WrapfuncNormal(A a, B b, int unused long& R, long& M, double& D) {funcNormal(a, b, R, M, D)}` and put `WrapfuncNormal` instead `funcNormal` into the `cfs` array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible because your functions have different signatures (these are different types). C ++ does not support arrays of elements of different types. But you can match signatures by adding unused parameter, it does not change anything at all, but allows you to put them in one container:

```
typedef void(*combineFunc)(A, B, int, long int&, long int&, double&);

void funcBlock(A a, B b, int C, long& R, long& M, double& D);
void funcNormal(A a, B b, int unused, long& R, long& M, double& D);

combineFunc cfs[] = { funcBlock, funcNormal };
```

Another way is to use an array of structures that can store all your functions, like so

```
struct combineFunc
{
   enum TYPE
   {
      NORMAL,
      BLOCK
   } type;

   combineFunc(void(*nf)(A, B, int, long int&, long int&, double&)) :
      type(NORMAL), nf_(nf)
   {
   }

   combineFunc(void(*fb)(A, B, long int&, long int&, double&)) :
      type(BLOCK), fb_(fb)
   {
   }

   union
   {
      void(*nf_)(A, B, int, long int&, long int&, double&);
      void(*fb_)(A, B, long int&, long int&, double&);
   };
};

CombineFunc cfs[] = { funcBlock, funcNormal };
```

Comment: No, sorry, that isn't what I meant. The word *unused* is fine as far as the word itself goes. See my answer if you wish. (But I like your answer, too, +1.)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I cant change my function paramaters. So i guess storing them in an array is impossible then.

Comment: @user6308605, What C++ standard  do you use?

Comment: c++11 @DmytroDadyka

Comment: @user6308605, in C++ 11 you can create container similar to `std::variant` based on `union` type. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is best answered with a question.

Within the loop, when you call `cf(arguments)`, what arguments would you write between the parentheses? Would the arguments include `C` or not?

I think that, if you answer this question, you will see why what you want probably cannot be done until your program has been redesigned a bit. The redesign might be as simple, though, as letting `funcNormal()` accept (and ignore) a dummy argument in place of `C`.

If the last suggestion is what you want, then

```
void funcNormal(A a, B b, int, long& R, long& M, double& D)
```

Notice that the `int`, because ignored, is unnamed.

Answer (score 3):

C++ is a statically typed language. Arrays are homogeneous: All elements of an array have exactly the same type.

A pointer to a function of one type is a different type from a pointer to another function type. Type of a function is determined by its argument and return types. As such, it is not possible to store pointers to functions of different argument lists in the same array.

There are however techniques for "type erasure", which allows simulation of dynamic typing. C++ standard library comes with two heterogeneous wrappers: `std::variant` and `std::any`. Variant is an implementation of a tagged union. It can be used to store an object from a pre-defined list of types. `any` is a type safe wrapper for `void*`. it can store an object of any type. So, an array of variant or `any` might be what you're looking for.

They are only low level tools though, and for more featured heterogeneous processing, there are existing libraries such as Boost.Hana.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a set of variable to call them with, and all of them have fixed types, you can wrap your functions inside lambdas to normalize their types:

```
using combineFunc = void(*)(A, B, int, long int&, long int&, double&);

combineFunc cfs[] = {
    [](A a, B b, int C, long& R, long& M, double& D){ funcBlock(a, b, C, R, M, D); },
    [](A a, B b, int, long& R, long& M, double& D){ funcNormal(a, b, R, M, D); }
};

// do whatever
```