# c++ How can i save function return type for lambda function without template?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, save, std-function

I'm trying to create class that can save function pointer, arguments and **return type**.

*my class that saves function*

```cpp
// Here i can't pass temlpate because next step for me is creating array of CFnSaver ('std::vector<CFnSaver*>')
// template<typename T>
class CFnSaver
{
public:
    // i can't use template here, compiler throw an error
    // template<typename T>
    std::function<int()> savedFn;

    template<typename ... Args>
    constexpr bool Save(void* pFn, Args ... args)
    {
        if (!pFn) return false;

        // creating lambda function
        auto lambdaFn = [pFn, args...]()
        {
            // I need to get function return type, not just hardcode 'int' (as i did)
            using tempFn = int(*)(Args ...);
            auto tempFunc = reinterpret_cast<tempFn>(pFn);
            return tempFunc(args...);
        };

        // Here i can call original function and get result, e.g. '5', but i don't need it here
        // auto res = lambdaFn(); 

        // saving lambda to std::function
        savedFn = lambdaFn;

        return !!savedFn;
    }


    inline CFnSaver() {};

    template<typename ... Args>
    inline CFnSaver(void* pFn, Args ... args) { Save(pFn, args...); }

    bool const operator ! () const { return(!savedFn); }

    explicit operator bool() const { return !!savedFn; }
};
```

*Usage example:*

```cpp
int printSum(int a, int b)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    printf_s("%d\n", sum);
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    CFnSaver cfn(printSum, 2, 3);

    // I need to get return of this function (now it's hardcoded to int)
    auto res = cfn.savedFn();

    return 0;
}
```

I also can create another version of my function, that passes another variable as ref.
But i'm not comfortable with it.

```cpp
void printSum(int a, int b, int& result)
{
    int sum = a + b;
    printf_s("%d\n", sum);
    result = sum;
}

int main()
{
    int result = 0;
    CFnSaver cfn(printSum, 2, 3, result);
    cfn.savedFn();

    return 0;
}
```

I think i need another way to saving function or i'm missing out some way to do it, any help is appreciated.

P.s. sorry for my poor english.

I'm tried template class, template function, passing variables as ref.

Comment: The type returned by `savedFn` must be known at compile time, and it must be the same for every instance of `CFnSaver`.  That's how the C++ type system works.

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26159021/12861639 ?

Comment: `return !!savedFn;` - when would this expression ever not evaluate to true? I don't see how `savedFn` would ever have a falsy value.

Comment: The source of error is your attempt to cast function pointer to `void*` in C way.  ANY pointer can be cast to `void*`. But function pointers aren't pointers, they cannot be.  A dirty way to do that can be something like `CFnSaver cfn(reinterpret_cast<void*>(printSum), 2, 3);` More safe way would be  to use `std::function`. Or `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Maybe you're better of explaining WHAT you are trying to do. I don't see how your CFnSaver is different from a lambda function.

Comment: The question is how to save the return values. But how do you indent to use the saved return values? If return values are from a limited set of types, you can save it to `std::variant`. If the set of possible return types is unlimited and you want to acquire them from, say, a possibly unbounded overrides of `virtual` function of a polymorphic type hierarchy, you can use `std::any` to keep results for later. If you don't use return values at all, but retain them so they play a role in an RAII way, `std::any` also would work.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I don't think it is possible without using templates.

My advice would be to instead of using an array of saved functions create a lambda to call them and use that instead. The lambda could even take an array of bools specifying whether to call specific functions or not if that's necessary.

**Edit:**

If the return types are the same, or the functions can be grouped into lists with the same retun type `std::bind` could be used. If :

```
std::vector<std::function<int()> vec {
    AddNumbers, // AddNumbers(int, int) adds two numbers
    std::bind(AddNumbers, std::placeholders::_1, 3) // Adds three to a number, usage example: vec[1](2); would return 5
}
```