# How to implement a generic vector of functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-function

I would like to implement something of this sort, and I don't think it's supported by the language.

```
std::vector< std::function< void(ANY TYPE) > > = v;
```

We have:

```
void f1(A*){}
void f2(B*){}
```

then,

```
v[0] = std::bind(f1,_1);
v[1] = std::bind(f2,_1);
```

then,

```
A* a = new A;
v[0](a);

B* b = new B;
v[1](b);
```

Is there any construct in C++ that will allow me to do something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++: std::vector of std::function with arbitrary signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565019/c-stdvector-of-stdfunction-with-arbitrary-signatures)

Comment: Nope, in the other example all arguments are pre-bound. So in effect the std::function signature is the same. Or am it missing something?

Comment: Boost.Variant -> http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/variant.html

Comment: What's the point of the exercise? Imagine that you somehow managed to create such a vector - how do you plan to use it? Putting those functions in a vector suggests you plan to call them from some generic code, like `int index = FigureOutWhich(); v[index](what_goes_here?);` but it's not clear how this generic code is supposed to know which arguments to pass.

Comment: I recieve the index of the vector, one I do, I fetch the functor, and call it appropriately based on the index

Comment: So basically you have something like `switch(index) { case 0: v[index](a); break; case 1: v[index](b); break;}`. Then you may just as well do `switch(index) { case 0: f1(a); break; case 1: f2(b); break;}`. You gain nothing from putting them into a vector, even if that were possible.

Comment: @Kam There's probably a type-safe solution to your general problem. Can you describe it?